# Colocar o executável no cliente sem ter que instalar SqlServer

Tags: c#

Desenvolvi uma aplicação no Visual Studio usando C# Windows Forms e banco de dados SQL Server 2017. 
Preciso colocar na máquina do cliente apenas o executável da aplicação e o arquivo de extensão .mdf, que é o arquivo gerado pelo SQL Server e contém o as informações do banco de dados. Ou seja, não quero ter que instalar o SQL Server na máquina do cliente, pois é um trabalho um pouco chato de se fazer. 
Teria alguma maneira de fazer isto ? Utilizar apenas o arquivo .mdf, sem ter que instalar o SQL Server ?

Comment: Basta fazer a conexão com a máquina servidora aonde está instalado o SQL Server. Na máquina cliente fica apenas a aplicação, veja o modelo cliente-servidor.

Comment: Bruno, a instalação do SQL server será sempre obrigatoria no cliente. Se a sua aplicação for gerar poucos dados recomento um SDF.

Comment: Tem jeito sim! Mas você teria que refazer todo o projeto em cima desse [componente](https://github.com/improvedk/OrcaMDF). Em contra partida perderia toda a escalonabilidade de arquitetura  proporcionada pelo SQL Server.